# Pass URL readfile adds server path

Tags: php, html

Initially what I am trying to do is pass a parameter to a script that then calls readfile.  However, even if I hard code it (see below).  When I view the source it is adding the path of the server into the read file.

```
//CODE
//$file = $_GET['url'];
$file = "https://someDomain.com/img/testFile1.jpg";
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile($file);
exit();

//OUTPUT
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="https://serverDomain.com/test.php?url=https://someDomain.com/img/testFile1.jpg">
```

Is this a settings issue with the server?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That looks like what Chrome does when you view an image. Are you actually viewing the source or inspecting the image with DEV tools? Chrome will wrap any image returned from the browser when inspecting.

Comment: In Chrome window it shows a white square with an outline.  In the tools area when I click "inspect" it shows the markup and the src tag adds the serverDomain plus the image domain and path.

Comment: Yeah, you can't actually view the source of an image, what happens is when Chrome receives an image, with image headers, it creates it's own webpage with your image and the current URL as the source. You won't get a webpage if you're returning an image.

Comment: It doesn't matter what browser, I have tried them all with the same result.  It is adding the server domain plus the hosted image domain to the src path.  Which is an incorrect path.  In safari and ff I get a blue square with the question mark.

Comment: You're not outputting the HTML. Your returning the binary image data according to your example code. What you see in your browser is the html generated by the browser so it can show off your image.